# How to read the ansible.cfg file variables in Ansible custom modules?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

Can anyone help me find how I can access the variables defined in *ansible.cfg* file into my Ansible modules Python code?

Comment: IMHO the namespaces are isolated. Put the configuration as a parameter of the module. Considering Ansible's lazy evaluation, the entry to the module will be the point of the variables' evaluation. Some Ansible internals are passed to a module by default. See [Internal arguments](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#internal-arguments).